# Как устроена топология "Шина"?

Tags: сеть

Мы сейчас в школе изучаем информатику, тема - сети.

Я не могу понять про топологию "Шина". Как именно к ней подсоединяются компьютеры, если шина это медный кабель? Как к этой шине подключается витая пара?

Comment: С таким подходом шина это не медный кабель, а резина на колесе 

Comment: Когда-то (в оригинале) это было сделано [так](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5)

Answer (score 1):

Топология - это лишь архитектурное решение, напрямую к кабелю ничего не подключается. Для взаимодействия устройств в сети используется соответствующее сетевое оборудование. Коммутаторы и маршрутизатор. У тебя дома, например, стоит ведь Wifi-роутер, так вот он и выполняет роль маршрутизатора. Также и в какой-нибудь организации, например, используется маршрутизатор, к которому подключаются компьютеры и иные устройства, если нужно - то и другие маршрутизаторы.